# Row and Column Picture of a 3 x 3 Singular Matrix (Strang P43, 2.1.32)

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are the first two columns of a 3 by 3 matrix $A$. Which third columns
>   $\mathbf{w}$ would make this matrix singular? Describe a typical column picture of $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ in that singular case, and a typical row picture (for a random $\mathbf{b}$).
>
> $\boxed{\text{(P38)  Column picture:}}$ $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ asks for a combination of columns to produce $\mathbf{b}$.
>
> $\boxed{\text{(P38)  Row picture:}}$ Each equation in $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ gives a line (n = 2) or a plane (n = 3) or a "hyperplane" (n > 3). They intersect at the solution or solutions, if any.
>
> **Answer:** $A$ is singular when its third column $\mathbf{w}$ is a combination $c\mathbf{u} + d\mathbf{v}$ of the first columns.
>   $\color{red}{\Large{[}}$ A typical column picture has $\mathbf{b}$ outside the plane of $\mathbf{u, v, w}. \color{red}{\Large{]}}$ $\color{#0070FF}{\Large{[}}$ A typical row picture has the intersection line of two planes parallel to the third plane. $\color{#0070FF}{\Large{]}}$ Then no solution.

"Singularity" hasn't been formally defined, but P27 identifies it with dependent columns. So the third column depends on the first two, ie: $\mathbf{w} =c\mathbf{u} + d\mathbf{v} \; \forall \; c, d \in \mathbb{R}$. Moreover, $\mathbf{w}$ is a plane on which the vectors $\mathbf{u, v}$ lie. I seize this paragraph.

$\large{1.}$ How and why is the red bracket true? $\qquad \large{2.}$ How and why is the blue bracket true?

Please mind that this question is from but Section 2.1 of *IoLA, 4th ed*, by Strang, so please keep answers rudimentary.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question:
the red bracket is true because b is randomly chosen, it can be either on the plane or out of the plane of **u, v, w**. Furthermore, the possibility that it's out of the plane is bigger than that it's on the plane.